# macromedia mx 2004 shows 'unsupported format file' for flash document v4.0

Tags: flash, flash-builder, flash-cs5, fla

I am new to Flash codding. I have .fla file of version 4.0. It contain links. I need open and change the links. I installed **MacroMedia MX 2004**. I am not able to open my .fla file.It display a message  **'unsupported  format file'** . Can anybody suggest me how to edit this file.

Comment: Since it is now 2013, maybe installing something a bit more up to date than Macromedia MX 2004 could be a good idea. There is a free trial of the current Flash CS6 (from Adobe, that bought Macromedia back in 2005) that you can use for 30 days: http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=flash